# Java - send different object to interface method

Tags: java

I have error when I send this:

```
myClaass.put(new ImenResult(1).Show());
myClaass.put(new ImenResult(2));
```

I understand why I have got this problem because I send to class which have interface parameter. My question is: what I have to add to interface to send this data and haven`t got error because this structure have to be this same (not my decision) because later I can send String or another things (Class). I know this is very difficult question.

Program:

```
Class_1 myClaass = new Class_1();
myClaass.put(new ImenResult(1).Show());
myClaass.put(new ImenResult(2));
myClaass.put(new ImenResult(3));
```

ImenResult:

```
public class ImenResult implements IImenResult{

    public Integer i;

    public ImenResult(Integer  i ) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer Show() {

        return i;
}
```

Class_1

```
public class Class_1 implements IQRack{

    public List<IAdant> adan;


    public void put(IAdant value) {
        adan.add(value);
    }

    }
```

IAdan

```
public interface IAdant  {

}
```

Thanks for help I told you this is difficult question (of course for people who are not Java specialist) but topic is fixed. I gave you points. Thanks again for helped.  [closed]

Comment: probably something like `put(IAdant) in type Class_1 ist not applicable for the parameters (Integer)`

Comment: Does `IImenResult` extend `IAdant`?

Comment: @DuncanJones. You mean extend?

Comment: @Tichodroma This advice show me eclipse - Change method 'put(IAdant)' to 'put(integer)' but I can`t edit 'put(IAdant)' because in future I have to send string or class string

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper. Don't think of future, before you get it right in present. You can't have your single method get and handle every kinds of argument, unless you really want to make things too complex. If you somehow, need in future to pass string, and you always have options to `overload` your method.

Comment: @RohitJain Well, yes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should implement the method `put(Integer)` in `Class_1` for this to work

```
public class Class_1 implements IQRack {

    public List<IAdant> adan;

    public void put(IAdant value) {
        adan.add(value);
    }

    void put(Integer Show) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
After your comment i think this is what you are trying to do:

```
public class Class_1 implements IQRack {

    private List<IAdant> adan = new ArrayList<IAdant>();

    public Class_1(IAdant i) {
        this.put(i);
    }

    void put(IAdant Show) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}

public class IAdant {

    Boolean bValue;
    String sValue;
    Integer iValue;

    public IAdant(Object o) {
        if (o.getClass().isInstance(new Integer(1))) {
            iValue = (Integer) o;
        } else if (o.getClass().isInstance(false)) {
            bValue = (Boolean) o;
        } else if (o.getClass().isInstance("")) {
            sValue = (String) o;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not fix problem because on time I send Constructor of Integer class another I send Integer or String or Boolean Value

Answer (score 3):

The line: `myClaass.put(new ImenResult(1).Show());` will fail, because `myClaass.put()` is expecting to get an object that implements `IAdant`, but you are sending and `Integer`. `Integer` does not implement `IAdant`.

Comment: I know this but problem is much more difficult because this method I can`t edit and I have to send Integer or Boolean or String or Class Constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
myClaass.put(new ImenResult(1).Show());
myClaass.put(new ImenResult(2));
```

first case would file, cuz, your put method expects IAdant(any that that implements IAdant) and you are passing an integer as the show method would return one.

second case would fail because of the same reason that your ImenResult class is not implementing or a Type of IAdant.

if you want the second case to work, implement IAdant in ImenResult class.

```
public class ImenResult implements IImenResult,IAdant{
//implement the methods from both the interfaces
}
```

now `myClaass.put(new ImenResult(2));` line would work with out any compiler errors.

If you wanna get the first case  myClaass.put(new ImenResult(1).Show()); to compile , you have to overload the put method in myClass class.

```
public void put(int val) {
        //do your logic here
    }
```

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper you'd still get error for the first case, as your put method expect an instance of IAdant and you are trying to pass an int.

Comment: I understand but this is school problem and I can`t edit this. I stop with my work because I have got this problem. 100% is idea to send to some method int, string, bollean or classes.

Comment: I understand this it`s look easy but this problem is very difficult because when I will send myClaass.put(new ImString(2)); I will got error. This interfase should take (Constructor Int, Int, Constructor String, String, Constructor Bollean, Bollean) in my opinion this topic is very interesting for good programers in Java.